# TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(....(....), ...., ....), .... unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When attempting:

```
gt_boxes = KL.Lambda(lambda x: norm_boxes_graph(
            x, K.shape(input_image)[1:3]))(input_gt_boxes)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kangaroo_training.py", line 91, in <module>
    model = mrcnn.model.MaskRCNN(mode='training', 
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3-4.10.3-10/envs/femos38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mask_rcnn_tf2-1.0-py3.8.egg/mrcnn/model.py", line 1848, in __init__
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3-4.10.3-10/envs/femos38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mask_rcnn_tf2-1.0-py3.8.egg/mrcnn/model.py", line 1890, in build
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3-4.10.3-10/envs/femos38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3-4.10.3-10/envs/femos38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py", line 925, in type_spec_from_value
    raise TypeError(f"Could not build a TypeSpec for {value} of "
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.math.truediv/truediv:0', description="created by layer 'tf.math.truediv'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.
```

I'm running:

```
$ python3 kangaroo_training.py
```

My imports look like:

```
import os
import random
import datetime
import re
import math
import logging
from collections import OrderedDict
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.backend as K
import keras.layers as KL
import keras.engine as KE
import keras.models as KM
```

This is running on an M1 Mac with Python 3.8.16 and tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal.